# The root node of sitemap is not working on Google Webmaster tools

Tags: xml, sitemap

I have a website on Godaddy and is working absolutely fine and i want to add a sitemap.xml to my website. I have added the below file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="~" title="httpdocs"  description="">
    <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home"  description="" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/Home.aspx" title="Home"  description="" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/Services.aspx" title="Services"  description="" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/ContactUs.aspx" title="Contact Us"  description="" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/AboutUs.aspx" title="About Us"  description="" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/Error.aspx" title="Error"  description="" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/Admin.aspx" title="Admin"  description="" />
    </siteMapNode>
    </siteMap>
```

Now I have a problem with the root node.Godaddy tells me that my rootnode is httpdocs and so when I try to add a sitemap.xml to my website through Google Webmaster tools and it gives me an error

> We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided and then resubmit. - General HTTP error: 404 not found
>   HTTP Error: 404

Comment: Can you also show the XML file?

Comment: I have attached the xml file too.Please help.